# Log4j 2 hangs when creating logger

Tags: java, log4j2

I have this simple program:

```
package myPackage;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

public class Test {
    private static Logger logger; 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Creating logger...");
        logger = LogManager.getLogger(Test.class); 
        System.out.println("Logger created.");
        logger.info("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

If I run the program under the debugger, it prints:

```
Creating logger...
```

and then hangs.

If I run the program without debugger, it prints:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.quickCheckMemberAccess(Reflection.java:84)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:489)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ReflectionUtil.getCallerClass(ReflectionUtil.java:128)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ReflectionUtil.getCallerClass(ReflectionUtil.java:205)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:42)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:329)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContext.getLogger(SLF4JLoggerContext.java:42)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.newLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.newLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:329)
    [... more of the same]
```

I am using Log4j 2 version 2.5 along with SLF4J version 1.7.18.

EDIT:  This is my class path:

```
// JRE 1.8.0_74

// Log4j 2
log4j-1.2-api-2.5.jar
log4j-1.2-api-2.5-javadoc.jar
log4j-1.2-api-2.5-sources.jar
log4j-api-2.5.jar
log4j-api-2.5-javadoc.jar
log4j-api-2.5-sources.jar
log4j-core-2.5.jar
log4j-core-2.5-javadoc.jar
log4j-core-2.5-sources.jar
log4j-core-2.5-tests.jar
log4j-flume-ng-2.5.jar
log4j-flume-ng-2.5-javadoc.jar
log4j-flume-ng-2.5-sources.jar
log4j-iostreams-2.5.jar
log4j-iostreams-2.5-javadoc.jar
log4j-iostreams-2.5-sources.jar
log4j-jcl-2.5.jar
log4j-jcl-2.5-javadoc.jar
log4j-jcl-2.5-sources.jar
log4j-jmx-gui-2.5.jar
log4j-jmx-gui-2.5-javadoc.jar
log4j-jmx-gui-2.5-sources.jar
log4j-jul-2.5.jar
log4j-jul-2.5-javadoc.jar
log4j-jul-2.5-sources.jar
log4j-nosql-2.5.jar
log4j-nosql-2.5-javadoc.jar
log4j-nosql-2.5-sources.jar
log4j-slf4j-impl-2.5.jar
log4j-slf4j-impl-2.5-javadoc.jar
log4j-slf4j-impl-2.5-sources.jar
log4j-taglib-2.5.jar
log4j-taglib-2.5-javadoc.jar
log4j-taglib-2.5-sources.jar
log4j-to-slf4j-2.5.jar
log4j-to-slf4j-2.5-javadoc.jar
log4j-to-slf4j-2.5-sources.jar
log4j-web-2.5.jar
log4j-web-2.5-javadoc.jar
log4j-web-2.5-sources.jar

// SLF4J 1.7.18
slf4j-api-1.7.18.jar
```

Comment: Can you try using this line instead? `LogManager.getContext().getLogger(getClass().getName());`

Comment: I have tried using `LogManager.getContext().getLogger(Test.class.getName())` because I am in a static method, but the problem persists (the first calls in the stack trace change, but then it is the same).

Comment: How about initializing your logger like so? `private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Test.class);`

Comment: Please edit your question to include a full list of all JARs (including version numbers) that your code is running with.

Comment: What JDK version are you using? Do you have a security manager enabled.

Comment: @Idos I had done that, but then moved all the instantiations into `main` to understand where the code was blocking.
@LukeWoodward I have added the list of JARs.
@rgoers JDK 1.8.0_74.  There is no security manager that I am aware of.

Comment: find the conflicting version and throw it. If you are using gradle, run this command to list all dependency jars `gradle dependencies > jars.log`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have more jars than you need. In particular, your application is not using SLF4J, so you don't need to include it.  But you have also included log4j-slf4j, log4j-core and log4j-slf4j-impl. Log4g-core is the actual Log4j 2 implementation. log4j-to-slf4j is an implementation of the Log4j 2 API that routes all events to SLF4J. log4j-slf4j-impl will then route the requests back to the Log4j api and the loop will start all over again.

You cannot have both the log4j-to-slf4j and log4j-slf4j-impl jars in the classpath. If you want Log4j 2 to do your logging then remove log4j-to-slf4j.

Also, your sample application is not a web application so you should not have log4j-web in the classpath.

Finally, unless you really want all the optional components like flume, no-sql, and jmx you should not include them.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously your classpath is polluted, these 2 can not be there at same time:

```
log4j-slf4j-impl-2.5.jar
log4j-to-slf4j-2.5.jar
```

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-slf4j-impl/index.html

> Use of the Log4j 2 SLF4J Binding (log4j-slf4j-impl-2.0.jar) together
>   with the SLF4J adapter (log4j-to-slf4j-2.0.jar) should never be
>   attempted, as it will cause events to endlessly be routed between
>   SLF4J and Log4j 2.

Detailed explanation here:

http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me - removed log4j-to-slf4j-2.5.jar